# Why does this sequence happen like this?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The other day I sent my girlfriend this text

<3

she sent me back

<3<3<3

not to be one upped I responded with

<3<3<3<3<3<3<3

this got very silly very quickly.

After our "<3" battle was over I got to thinking about the pattern we were forming. Since we were doubling the number of hearts and adding one I thought the sequence would be something like 2^n + 1. BUT IT IS NOT. It is 2^n - 1 .

Why is this?

Comment: Because if you have $2^k + d$, double it and add one, you get $2^{k+1} + 2d + 1$. The difference is maintained iff it is $d = -1$.

Comment: This is one of the most awesome question on Math.SE :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you started with $1=2^1-1$.  Then $2*1+1=2*(2^1-1)+1=2^2-1$.  Generally $2(2^n-1)+1=2^{n+1}-1$  When you double the $-1$ and add $1$, you get $-1$ back again.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern clearly holds for the first few terms. Let's see if going from step $n$ to step $n+1$ keeps with the pattern.

$a_n=2^n-1$. Then
$$
a_{n+1}=2a_n+1=2(2^n-1)+1=2^{n+1}-2+1=2^{n+1}-1.
$$